# Is any variety generated by a recursively presented group always recursive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, computability, universal-algebra, finitely-generated

Let’s denote the minimal variety of groups (a class of all groups, that satisfy a given set of identities of equivalently a class of groups that is closed under subgroups, quotients and direct products) that contains a group $G$ as $Var(G)$, the [relatively free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object)  of rank $n$ for the variety $\mathfrak{U}$ as $F_n(\mathfrak{U})$.

> Is it always true, that if $G$ is [recursively presented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_presented_group), then so is $F_n(Var(G))$?

Alternatively, this question can be formulated the following ways:

> Is it always true that if $G$ is recursively presented, then $Var(G)$ can be defined by a recursively enumerable set of identities?

> Is it always true that if $G$ can be embedded into a finitely presented group, then $F_n(Var(G))$ also can?

The third variant of the question is equivalent to the first two due to [Higman embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_embedding_theorem)

However, neither of these formulations gives me any idea how to approach this problem…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yu. Kleiman constructed a finitely generated recursively presented group $G$ such that the variety $var(G)$ is not defined by a recursively enumerable set of identities. See the math review MR0688918.